# Volume of the first octant under a surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the first octant region under the surface $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}=1$

I think that the integral should be:

$$\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^{\left(1-\sqrt x\right)^2}\int_{0}^{\left(1-\sqrt x -\sqrt y\right)^2}\,dz\,dy\,dx$$

Could someone tell me if this is correct?

Comment: it is correct !

Comment: i am interested about bounds of integral,could you tell me please i little detailed about it?

Comment: you can write $z = (1-\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2$ , ie z has that range

Comment: about $x$ and $y$?

Comment: once you cover the height than you need find the area for which $z$ is not needed and hence $y$ from $0$ to $(1-\sqrt{x})^2$

Comment: and finally only $x$ remains , if you apply the same strategy you will get $\sqrt{x}=1$ and hence x from $0$ to $1$

Comment: This is a [superellipsoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipsoid) with $A=B=C=1$ and $r=t=\dfrac12$. The formula of its entire volume is in the article. Of course, you'll only need and eighth of that. As to why these shapes are related to the [beta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and [gamma functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2013_May_7#Linking_Factorials_to_Geometric_Shapes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And an even simpler method for finding this integral is replacing $x$ with $u^2$ , $y$ with $v^2$ and $z$ with $w^2$.

Instead of this : 
$$\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^{\left(1-\sqrt x\right)^2}\int_{0}^{\left(1-\sqrt x -\sqrt y\right)^2}\,dz\,dy\,dx$$
$dx = 2u\,du\\dy=2v\,dv\\dz=2z\,dz$

you will get this :

$$\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^{1-u}\int_{0}^{1-u-v}8uvw\,dw\,dv\,du$$

which i think is easier to visualize